# Yii 2 - Difference between using Yii::$app->request and Yii::$app->getRequest(), which is Recommended to use?

Tags: php, yii2

There are two methods to get request or other component, but which is better to use?

```
Yii::$app->request
Yii::$app->getRequest()
```

Answer (score 1):

`request` is a property of the `Yii::$app` object while `getRequest()` is its getter method. The base object class for Yii [`\Yii\base\Object`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html) defines properties as follows:

> A property [e.g `label`] is defined by a getter method (e.g. `getLabel`), and/or a setter method (e.g. `setLabel`). [...] A property can be accessed like a member variable of an object. Reading or writing a property will cause the invocation of the corresponding getter or setter method.

There is no specific rule for which should be used but the unwritten convention in the official docs and examples is to use the property rather than the setter. So go with `Yii::$app->request`